# Is is true that if $E|X_n - X| \to 0$ then $E[X_n] \to E[X] $?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

My question is motivated by the following problem:

Show that if $|X_n - X| \le Y_n$ and $E[Y_n] \to 0$ then $E[X_n] \to E[X]$.

I started off by saying that since
$$|X_n - X|\ge 0 $$
then $$E[|X_n - X|]\ge 0 $$ At the same time 
$$E[|X_n - X|]\le E[Y_n] $$

and so

$$0 \le E[|X_n - X|] \le E[Y_n]$$

By the squeeze theorem then $E[|X_n - X|] \to 0$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

I know that if $E[|X_n - X|] = 0$ then I  can set up a contradiction, like so:

Suppose that $|X_n - X| = c$, $c \ne 0$ and $E[|X_n - X|] = 0$. Then $$E[|X_n - X|] = E[c] = c \ne 0. $$

But I don't know how to show this would hold in the limit. I am planning to use this to show that $X_n \to X$ and therefore $E[X_n] \to E[X]$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\vert E(X) - E(X_n) \vert =\vert E(X-X_n) \vert  \leq E(|X-X_n|) \to 0$

Comment: by Jensen's inequality

Comment: It's simpler than Jensen inequality;
$-|Y| \leq Y \leq |Y|$ then by monotony and linearity of expectation $-E|Y| \leq E(Y) \leq E|Y|$ hence $|E(Y)|\leq E|Y|$.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying by contrapositive: If $E[X_n] \not\to E[X]$, then by linearity, $E[X_n-X]\not\to 0$.  And your result should follow.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How are you applying linearity here?

Comment: I'm using $E[X_n-X]=E[X_n]-E[X]$